# DataGrid UWP/WinUI SelectAll function?

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

How to select all rows in datagrid for uwp/winui?
Similar to dataGrid.SelectAl(); from WPF.

I didn't find anything about this in uwp/winUI

Comment: There is currently no datagrid control in UWP or WinUI. Are you talking about the datagrid control from the Community Toolkit or some third party library?

Comment: from the Community Toolkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all items by pressing the **Control** key and the **A** key.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <Button
        Click="SelectAllButton_Click"
        Content="SelectAll" />
    <controls:DataGrid
        x:Name="DataGridControl"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectionMode="Extended" />
</StackPanel>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Items.Add(new Item() { Id = 0, Title = "A" });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Id = 1, Title = "B" });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Id = 2, Title = "C" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new();

    private void SelectAllButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataGridControl.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);

        var keys = new[]
        {
            new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo()
            {
                VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.Control),
                KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None,
            },
            new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo()
            {
                VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.A),
                KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None,
            },
        };

        InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();

        // Press the keys.
        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(keys);

        foreach (InjectedInputKeyboardInfo key in keys)
        {
            key.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
        }

        // Release the keys.
        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(keys);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was occurring in the array, for some reason, it was not working, I solved it by just sending the keys separately

Thanks, @Adrew!

```
this.dataGrid.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);

        var inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
        // Press the keys.
        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo
        {
            VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.Control,
            KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None
        }});

        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo
        {
            VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.A,
            KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None
        }});

        // Release the keys.
        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo
        {
            VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.Control,
            KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp
        }});

        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo
        {
            VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.A,
            KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp
        }});
```